# Apache serve files with NTFS permissions?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, ldap, wordpress, directory

I hope I came to the right sub for this question.

Basically here is the scenario:

You have folder name Testfolder which is hosted on Apache. Test folder has files that only certain users on the domain can read see them.

Example file1.htm = Can only be viewed by all users file2.htm = Can only be viewed by Domain Admin, Guy2, Guy3

So when you acess them via example \WebServer\Site Name\testfolder\file1 & file2.htm they are viewed correctly by their respective users.

However when you go to testwebsite.com/testfolder , all files are viewed by anyone and ignore the folder permissions. Any ideas on why that is happening? If anyone could help with this issue it would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Also the way permissions are set are through NTFS - see below Right click file > properties > security > add users that are allowed to view the file.

Note: This is on Windows 2008R2

Question is there a way to authorize users on a domain to view files & folders though?

## Virtual Host

```
DocumentRoot "D:\wordpress"
ServerName "testserver1"
ServerAlias "testserver1.com"
<Directory "D:\wordpress\Test Files">
    AllowOverride None
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the authorized users to an AD group and then use the appropriate directives in Apache to query the AD, and only allow access to users in that group.  Or you could restrict them to specific users....but for easy maintainability I'd go with an AD group.

You might look at the section in the Apache documentation:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html

Comment: Just making sure but, apache cant read+use permissions set on files with if you do the  "Right click file > properties > security > add users that are allowed to view the file" ?